# How can I initialize members of a class based on a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, class, generics, initialization

I want to implement a class that uses N-dimensional vectors (from the mathematical point of view). I'm using Vec objects from the opencv library, and their signature looks like this: `Vec<typename _Tp, int cn>` where `cn` is the number of elements inside that vector. I must provide a constant for the `cn` parameter.

I want my class to look something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    Vec<float, dim> m_center;
    vector<Vec<float, dim>> m_points;
// ...
}
```

and I want to be able to initialize `dim` dinamically, that is create a `MyClass` object that has its `dim` set to whatever number I want. How can I correctly approach this problem in C++?

Comment: `template <std::size_t dim> class MyClass` ?

Comment: do you wanted to use constructor and pass parameter ?

Comment: if `dim` isn't know at compile type but must be for `Vec`, then you have to find alternative to `Vec` (as `std::vector`).

Comment: Or maybe wait for [JIT Compilation Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1609r1.html).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, the dimension isn't known at compile time. I wanted to use ```Vec``` because of convenience, as the addition, dot product and other vector operations are already implemented.

Comment: If you have small possible values, you might (runtime) dispatch to all of the possible values. (`if (i == 1) f<1>(); else if (i == 2) f<2>();`...)

Comment: @Jardo42 thank you. I think I'm gonna settle for this because my ```dim``` can only take integer values ranging from 1 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T, int N=9>
class Vec
{
public:
    Vec()
    {
        //auto deleter = [](T* t) { delete[] t; };
        //unique_ptr <T, decltype(deleter)> test(new T[N], deleter); //customized deleter omitted
        t = new T[N];
    }
    Vec(const Vec &v)
    {
        sz = v.sz;
        t = new T[sz];
    }
    string getType()
    {
        return typeid(T).name();
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        return sz;
    }
    ~Vec()
    {
        delete [] t;
    }

private:
    T *t;
    int sz = N;
};

template<int dim = 1>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        m_points.resize(2);
    }
    Vec<float, dim> getCenter()
    {
        return m_center;
    }

    vector<Vec<float, dim>> getPoints()
    {
        return m_points;
    }

private:
    Vec<float, dim> m_center;
    vector<Vec<float, dim>> m_points;
};
```

**Test code:**

```
int main()
{
    MyClass<10> my;

    cout << "center size = " << my.getCenter().getSize() << endl;
    cout << "center type =" << my.getCenter().getType().c_str() << endl;

    cout << "points size" << my.getPoints().size() << endl;

    cout << "first point size = " << my.getPoints()[0].getSize() << endl;
    cout << "first point type =" << my.getPoints()[0].getType().c_str() << endl;

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
center size = 10
center type =float
points size2
first point size = 10
first point type =float
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

compile time value cannot be runtime value.

If range of value is small enough, you might generate all possible values and dispatch afterward.

It seems you just have to handle 1, 2 and 3, so something like:

```
template <std::size_t dim>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void DoFullJob();
private:
    Vec<float, dim> m_center;
    vector<Vec<float, dim>> m_points;
// ...
};


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> i;

    switch (i) {
        case 1: { MyClass<1>{}.DoFullJob(); break; }
        case 2: { MyClass<2>{}.DoFullJob(); break; }
        case 3: { MyClass<3>{}.DoFullJob(); break; }
        default: // Error message, or nothing...
    }
}
```

For bigger ranges, switch case might be replaced by array of functors generated by `std::index_sequence`.